# Addition of number of polynomials without using structure

Tags: c, arrays, addition, polynomials

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, n, m, c[20], s = 0;
    int *p[100];
```

I ask the user to enter the number of polynomial equations to add:

```
    printf("Enter the number of equations to add:\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
```

and ask the user to enter number of coefficients he is planning to use

```
    printf("Enter the maximum coefficient size of largest equation:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
        printf("Enter the coefficients of equation number %d:\n", j);
        p[j] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        for (i = n; i > 0; i--)
            scanf("%d", p[j] + i);
        printf("The equation %d becomes as follows:\n", j);
        i = n;
        printf("%dx^%d", *(p[j] + i), i - 1);
        for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
            printf("+%dx^%d", *(p[j] + i), i - 1);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

the code works ok up to here but I am having problem to add polynomials

```
    printf("On adding all equations we get:\n");
    for (i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            s = s + (*(p[j] + i));
            c[i] = s;
        }
    }
    i = n;
    printf("%dx^%d", c[i], i - 1);
    for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--)
        printf("+%dx^%d", c[i], i - 1);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

also I dont want to use any kind of other methods if possible... and can we multiply polynomials similarly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change

> for(j=1;j<=m;j++){

to

```
for(s=0,j=1;j<=m;j++){
```

your code gives correct output if dynamic memory allocated in differenet locations and garbage values are zeros.

You are allocating n*sizeof(int) memory for p[j]th pointer

> ```
> p[j]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
> for(i=n;i>0;i--)
>     scanf("%d",p[j]+i);
> ```

That means you can access from **p[j]+0 to p[j]+n-1**. If read some element to p[j]+n that means you are accessing memory which doesn't belong to you.
I modified code a bit which is working fine

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,n,m,c[20] = {0},s=0;
    int *p[100];
    printf("Enter the number of equations to add:\n");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    printf("Enter the maximum coefficient size of largest equation:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(j=1;j<=m;j++){
        printf("Enter the coefficients of equation number %d:\n",j);
        p[j]=(int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
            scanf("%d",p[j]+i);
        printf("The equation %d becomes as follows:\n",j);
        i=n-1;
        printf("%dx^%d",*(p[j]+i),i);
        for(i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
            printf("+%dx^%d",*(p[j]+i),i);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("On adding all equations we get:\n");
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
        for(s=0,j=1;j<=m;j++){
            s=s+(*(p[j]+i));
        c[i]=s;
        }
    }
    i=n-1;
    printf("%dx^%d",c[i],i);
    for(i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
        printf("+%dx^%d",c[i],i);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Don't forgot to add check for scanf and malloc.